# How to extend server timeout?

Tags: sql, asp.net, timeout

I'm facing with a trouble about timeout.
I have 2 servers: server for testing and server Production.
2 servers point one build and the same database but in server testing I can import excel file with more 90.000 rows however in server production has timeout expired "Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding." I check the config of 2 sql servers but they are the same config.
Can you help me to solve this problem?

Comment: Are two server with same spec..?

Comment: 2 servers is SQL 2k8

Comment: Check my answer for your solution//

Answer (score 0):

Use below code in your `web.config` file

```
 <system.web>
 <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="102400" executionTimeout="3600" requestValidationMode="2.0"/>
  </system.web>
```

Comment: I already set  <httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" executionTimeout="86400" shutdownTimeout="86400" maxRequestLength="16384" /> but it doesnt work. I set like your suggestion but it doesnt work too.

Comment: shutdownTimeout="86400"  not require